# Difference between AmazonDynamoDBClient and DynamoDB classes in their java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Amazon's DynamoDB java SDK and want to know the difference between the [AmazonDynamoDBClient](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.java) and [DynamoDB](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/DynamoDB.java) classes. I can't seem to find anything on them since there appears to be very little documentation. Is there any reason I should use one or the other? Are their any major benefits or drawbacks?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a good question.  It looks like `DynamoDB` is a wrapper to the `AmazonDynamoDBClient`, providing a different interface.  So this may be obvious and not the answer you are looking for but let me describe some of the differences between them.

The `createTable` method in `AmazonDynamoDBClient` returns back a `CreateTableResult` object, whereas the `DynamoDB`'s createTable method returns back a `Table` object.  This `Table` object can then be used to do CRUD on that table.  The `Table` object starts looking like a generic ORM object for DynamoDB.  So its not really `DynamoDB` class vs `AmazonDynamoDBClient`, its more like `DynamoDB` & `Table` classes vs `AmazonDynamoDBClient`.

`AmazonDynamoDBClient` is obviously older than the `DynamoDB` class.  `DynamoDB` is pretty new, coming out in 1.9.x.  But there is another class here worth mentioning, `DynamoDBMapper`.  `DynamoDBMapper` allows for even more ORM like operations.  Allowing developers to annotate their JavaBean data-model's so that they can easily be CRUD'd against a DynamoDB table.  You get to work with your objects directly and the `DynamoDBMapper` will do the CRUD work on the DynamoDB database.  `DynamoDBMapper` is older than the `DynamoDB` class.  I think maybe some developers did not want to work with the `DynamoDBMapper` (maybe not a fan of OO or annotations?) and there needed to be another paradigm, but I'm only hypothesizing.  So the `DynamoDB` and `Table` classes were created.  With the `Table` class you can interact with your tables more easily than the `AmazonDynamoDBClient` but without the overhead of creating JavaBean data-models that the `DynamoDBMapper` require.