# DynamoDB - how to check that an existing table is empty or non-empty

Tags: java, scala, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to implement a function that given a DynamoDB and the name of a table I know exists in the database, determines whether this table is empty or not.

I expect the signature to look like the following in Java:

`public Boolean isEmpty(DynamoDB database, String tableName) = ???`

Assume for the purposes of this question that the table has a primary key consisting of a single Integer type attribute called "UserId".

I'm aware that one can use a scan to look at a table, but I (a) don't know what the expression would look like, and (b) need it to be limited to a single item, so that we don't have to scan the entire table (which may be large) in the case that it is non-empty.

EDIT:

Should I perhaps be using an `AmazonDynamoDB` in my constructor instead, rather than a `DynamoDB`? The former has a `scan` method which takes a `ScanRequest` - for which you can easily set a limit using `.limit(1)` - whereas for the latter I would do something like `database.getTable(tableName).scan(...)`, but this scan takes a `ScanSpec` for which it is not clear to me how to set a limit for.

Comment: Scan has a Limit parameter, so try using that first?

Comment: hi @Hitobat, I've added an edit explaining my confusion around setting the limit parameter in the implementation I currently have, hope this clarifies my question somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to my own question, I found the following: 
[Difference between AmazonDynamoDBClient and DynamoDB classes in their java SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773525/difference-between-amazondynamodbclient-and-dynamodb-classes-in-their-java-sdk)

The `DynamoDB` I was trying to use is simply a wrapper around `AmazonDynamoDB` that provides a slightly different API. Using the `AmazonDynamoDB` instead makes the implementation of this function a lot easier, and it should look something like this (please excuse bad Java code, I'm actually writing this in Scala):

```
public Boolean isEmpty(AmazonDynamoDB database, String tableName) = {
   ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(tableName).withLimit(1);
   return database.scan(scanRequest).getCount == 0;
}
```

Or, in Scala:

```
def isEmpty(database: AmazonDynamoDB, tableName: String): Boolean = {
   val scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(tableName).withLimit(1)
   database.scan(scanRequest).getCount == 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do it in Java, but it must be similar to Javascript:

```
const params = {
  TableName: tableName,
  Limit: 1, // `Limit` is the most important parameter.
            // The scan will not scan the whole table, 
            //   it will only visit one item and then return. 
            // Very efficient!
};

// Execute the scan, whatever the syntax is...
const result = await (new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient().scan(params).promise());

// Check the response
if (result.Count > 0) return false; // the table is **not** empty 
return true; // the table is empty
```

In Java the code should be similar... feel free to ask for details it is not clear enough.